# Import CSV file into Microsoft azure Stream Analytics

Tags: csv, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm new in this area. I have right now a file original in excelc(data from sensor), i want to upload it into azure and use stream to process it, as the format of data supports CSV, I'm think about saving the excel in csv and upload it in blob storage (or should I send it into event hub?), however the stream analytics shows nothing in output. The original file looks like below, does anyone know something about this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post so that the text is not a link.

Comment: Post your query please. Post the settings around out of order events and tolerances. Post the modified date on the CSV in blob storage and post what you chose as your start time when you started the ASA job

Comment: Why Stream Analytics? Do CSV files arrive in blob storage in near real time? Do you have more than one CSV file at a time?

Comment: Adding to what GregGalloway said. Can you describe your scenario more, do you have an unbounded stream of such csv files coming in? What kind of queries do you want to run over such a stream and where do you want to persist the results?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers, I´ve tryed succesfully with uploading the first file, does anybody know how should I do with several CSV files? The query is e.g. like select Antenna, count(*) as Count, Avg(Doppler),
from input TIMESTAMP BY TimeStamp
group by Antenna, TumblingWindow(second, 10)(Also a problem with:Time format dosent conform to ISO 8601 standard)

Comment: Hi Xinyue,  Again, please describe your scenario better. If blob storage is your input, you can upload the csv files in time partitioned folders and ASA will continuously pick them up. Note that ASA is for stream processing, your initial question seems to indicate that you are using it for one off conversions.If you describe a hypothetical but more concrete scenario we can answer better.